# Optimality and convergence of Alternating Minimization approaches

Tags: reference-request, optimization, soft-question, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have an optimization problem in four variable and fortunately, the problem is convex in each variable while keeping others fixed.  I want to use alternating minimization (AM) based algorithm to find the optimal solution.

My optimization problem is given below,
$$
\min_{U,V,P,Q} \; \|X-UV\|_{F}^2 + \|K-PQ\|_{F}^2 + \|Y-UQ\|_{F}^2 + \|U\|_{F}^2 + \|V\|_{F}^2 + \|Q\|_{F}^2
$$
and the variables are $U, V, P $ and $Q$, and the norm used in Frobenius norm.  There is an additional constraints that $U$ and $Q$ are non-negative.
My question is, what are the optimality guarantee and convergence result for AM algorithms when there are more than two variables ?. Anyone can point me to some literature discussing such ?

Comment: Great question. I also wonder about it.

Comment: There's a huge literature on "block coordinate descent" and "alternating minimization" methods, but the available results depend on the particular structure and properties of the function.  Your function is convex in each of the four variables while keeping the others fixed.  I'm assuming that it's not convex as a whole?  Is it smooth?   Any other special structure?

Comment: @BrianBorchers . Yes it is not convex as a whole and yes it is smooth.

Comment: Unless you can provide more information about your particular problem, the answer is going to be "it depends."

Comment: I assume that you're minimizing the objective function, right?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Yes. Minimization only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One specific result that might be relevant is Proposition 2.3.1 (page 151) in D. Bertsekas, *Nonlinear Programming*, 3rd ed. 2016.

The result is that if there is a unique solution to each of the coordinatewise minimization problems, then any limit point of the sequence of solutions is a stationary point (which could be a minimum or a saddle point.)

If the level sets of $f$ are bounded (and hence compact), you can be assured that there will be at least one limit point- otherwise your sequence of solutions might just drift off to infinity.

Comment: what if there are non-negativity constraints on the variables ?.  In that case can we say that limit  point is either a local minima or a saddle point ?.  Or, at least does it converge to a stationary point ?

Comment: Nonnegativity by itself isn't going to be enough.

Comment: do have any suggestion on what other condition will guarantee a local minima ?

Comment: No.  As I commented earlier, if you'd provide more detail on your problem it might be possible for someone to provide a more helpful answer.

Comment: My problem is   $\|X-UV\|^2 + \|K-PQ\|^2 + \|Y-UQ\|^2 + \|U\|^2 + \|V\|^2 + \|Q\|^2$  with non-negativity constraints on U and Q

Comment: Please edit this into your question with an explanation of which variables you're optimizing over and what the known data is.  Also be clear on what norm (Frobenius norm or operator norm) you're interested in.

Comment: I updated the question with the required details.

Answer (score 1):

There are many works on this topic. For example look at this paper and its references: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.02746.pdf